# Need to write a SQL query to fetch data from a Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to write a SQL query which can fetch a data from one table A.

Senario -  Lets take table A has only two column C1 and C2. C1 has row_id's and C2 has vaues like "Site=google;site=gmail,site=yahoo"

Requirment - Need to write a query which can fetch all the row_id from column C1 of table A but the value should come for column C2 as "google;gmail;yahoo". Means it should not show "Site=" for all the values of C2 column in the data fetch. And one more condition that if there is , in place of ; in the value then query should convert it into ; and show the data.

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
SELECT C1, REPLACE(REPLACE(C2, 'Site=', ''), ',', ';') AS C2
  FROM TABLE
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: You need another replace to take Site= and site= into account: SELECT  REPLACE(replace(replace('Site=google;site=gmail,site=yahoo', 'Site=', ''), 'site=', ''), ',', ';') AS C2
  FROM dual

Comment: Thanks for your help..I got resuld :)

Comment: @Rene - I thought about that, but decided it was better to leave it as posted to keep it clearer.  The OP can add more REPLACE's (or change it to REPLACE(LOWER(C2), 'site=', '') if wanted.