# Need to write a SQL query to fetch data from a Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Need to write a SQL query to fetch data from a Oracle database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091642/need-to-write-a-sql-query-to-fetch-data-from-a-oracle-database)

I need to write a SQL query which can fetch a data from one table A.

Senario - Lets take table A has only two column C1 and C2. C1 has row_id's and C2 has vaues like "Site=google;site=gmail;yahoo"

Requirment - Need to write a query which can fetch all the row_id from column C1 of table A but the value should come for column C2 as "yahoo". Means if anything starts with "Site=" in any value of C2 column then it should not been shown in the data fetch.

Comment: Exact duplicate of "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091642/need-to-write-a-sql-query-to-fetch-data-from-a-oracle-database"?

Comment: @TToni: I just re-read this and thought to myself that my SO hadn't refreshed properly lol

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select
   *
from
   tableA
where 
   c2 not like 'site=%'
```

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the question.

Comment: No Jon, I think you got this wrong. Example - Suppose if a value is "Site=google;site=gmail;yahoo" then query should fetch "yahoo" only.

Comment: Ah, I see - give me a minute...

Comment: I see there's an answer on the other copy of this question. I'll leave it there.

Comment: Jon that was different question..Here is different. If you can, then please answer it here. It would be great help.